# Calling a user's DLL from Google script

Tags: dll, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am woking on a google script, which is performing some thermodynamic calculations. The script is linked to a google spreadsheet for reading input data and for writing results as well.

An issue is that in the script I need to determine some water steam properties in order to perform the calculations. However, such properties are not constant and they have to be determined by calling a DLL containing water steam properties functions.

Is there any approach how to call a function from an external (a user's) DLL in a google script?

Since a source code of the DLL for Matlab and VBA (from an Excel's macro) is available, another (but significantly more arduous) option is to rewrite the code into javascript, am I right?

Comment: impossible to call a dll from apps script. serverside code cant access your machine, and clientside cant call anyhing outside the browser.

Comment: Not impossible, but not trivial. You would have to expose the DLL as a webservice that can be called from apps script or you can write a native application that used the DLL that calls your script VIA the Execution API.